# Can I cut the paper off moldy drywall on back side?

Tags: bathroom, drywall

Inside the wall cavity of shower surround, I found some moldly patches. Wondering if appropriate to score the paper at the perimeter at studs, then peel if off, knowing this wall will be sealed up when shower is completed?

I realize there may be loss of some gypsum, but this wall is covered on the outside with 1/4" beadboard/paneling from the 1960s, which is quite durable.

[image]

Comment: Does the drywall feel mushy/soft?  The paper is what keeps it together as a board.  Would probably mist some bleach on it, and let a fan blow on it for a day to dry out.

Comment: No, that should not be done, it will weaken the drywall, you also have some wood rot, best treat that area with mold treatment

Comment: @crip659 agreed, hit it with some bleach, dry it out, then paint it with Kilz.    If its mushy, they have a bigger problem. and to knowitall, you spotted the rotten wood, i missed that, it looks like some of this is furred out, probably not too hard to replace.